# EditText with hint symbol by symbol

Tags: android, android-edittext, textwatcher, hint

When I am using regular hint in editText it is disappear with the first entered symbol. but on the gif image we can see another behavior and it's look much pretty :)

Any idea how it can be done?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you can achieve this using a TextWatcher. Do not use default hint. Use TextView with gray color which looks like a hint.
Align bottom the TextView to EditText and put some padding.

Comment: I thought about this )
but in little bit different direction: put textView behind editText field, and do the same staff... this trick will work, but i think there i some different way how they done this